# python - regex match all substrings starting with specic character (www) and end with whitespace

Tags: python, regex, substring, match

I am trying to match all urls in a string, but cannot find a way to match everything in particular substring/url without matching also everything after it.

string:
`available at: www.bankofengland.co.uk/prudential-regulation/\ntransforming-data-collection .\n40. News release ‘Data Collection Transformation Plan’, February 2021: www.bankofengland.co.uk/\nnews/2021/february/data-collection-transformation-plan .\n41. Under Section 166 of the Financial Services and Markets Act 2000.\n42. PRA Letter ‘Letter from`

i only want to match:
`www.bankofengland.co.uk/prudential-regulation/\ntransforming-data-collection`
`www.bankofengland.co.uk/\nnews/2021/february/data-collection-transformation-plan`

trying something like `www\.\w+.*\s{1}` but the match doesn't end with a whitespace and instead matches everything, could you please help me out?

Comment: found out this one works just fine:

`

# needs to be done only if urls contain newline characters
temp=re.sub(r"\n", "", string)

re.sub(r"(https://*)?(www.+?)\s{1}", "",  temp)
 
'available at: .40. News release ‘Data Collection Transformation Plan’, February 2021: .41. Under Section 166 of the Financial Services and Markets Act 2000.42. PRA Letter ‘Letter from'

`

Answer (score 0):

I think that this works:

```
import re

input_string = "available at: www.bankofengland.co.uk/prudential-regulation/\ntransforming-data-collection .\n40. News release ‘Data Collection Transformation Plan’, February 2021: www.bankofengland.co.uk/\nnews/2021/february/data-collection-transformation-plan .\n41. Under Section 166 of the Financial Services and Markets Act 2000.\n42. PRA Letter ‘Letter from"

urls = re.findall(r'(?:(?<!\S)(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)\S+(?:\/\S+)?(?:\n\S+(?:\/\S+)?)?', input_string)

print(urls)
```

The regular expression is this:

```
(?:(?<!\S)(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)\S+(?:\/\S+)?(?:\n\S+(?:\/\S+)?)?
```

I used a tool to make it so I think it may be a simplified version of it

Answer (score 0):

In fact, in a simpler way

```
result = re.findall(r'(www\..+\n.*)\s\.\n', string)
```